# Runtime introspection in C++

Tags: c++, class, introspection, object-slicing

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    void doSomething() { // nothing here };
}
```

and it also has a subclass that looks like this

```
class MyChildClass : MyClass {
    public:
    void doSomething() { // actual code here };
}
```

As you can see the `doSomething()` function does nothing in the parent class, but the child class overwrites it and adds actual code. My problem is that I am attempting to do something like this:

```
MyClass foo = MyChildClass();
foo.doSomething();
```

I was quite shocked to find that in this case, `MyClass`, and not `MyChildClass`'s version of `doSomething()` is called, even though foo is actually of type `MyChildClass`. I have far more experience in Objective-C than C++ so this is very strange for me. It seems that C++ is determining which version of `doSomething()` needs to be called at compile-time, rather than inspecting the type of the object at run-time and calling the correct version.

This is problematic for me, because in my actual code what I have is one parent class and multiple different child classes that inherit from it. Each of these child classes overwrites the `doSomething()` function with their own unique implementation. I end up having an `std::vector` full of `MyClass` objects (which is really full of many different types of objects that each inherit from `MyClass`) and I want to loop through each of these object and invoke their version of `doSomething()` without actually knowing their type at compile-time. This would be easy in Objective-C, but is there any way for me to accomplish this in C++?

Answer (score 6):

You need two things:

- A reference or pointer to the created object, so that it isn't copy-sliced.
- Having the member function `virtual` in the base class.

E.g., off the cuff,

```
struct MyClass{ virtual void foo() {} };
struct Derived: MyClass { void foo() override { /* ... */ } };

auto main() -> int
{
    MyClass&& o = Derived{};
    o.foo();
}
```

But why not just use the `Derived` type for the declaration?

---

> **”** I end up having an std::vector full of MyClass objects (which is really full of many different types of objects that each inherit from MyClass) and I want to loop through each of these object and invoke their version of doSomething() without actually knowing their type at compile-time.

A `vector<MyClass>` slices each item to just the `MyClass` part. You can use a vector of pointers. If these are owning pointers, use a smart pointer like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you! I made the function virtual in the parent's header file and also used a vector of pointers instead of the objects directly. I didn't know that std::vector slices the classes like that. My code works as expected now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run function based on run time information, you need to declare function as virtual function.

Comment: Kindly use Comments section for comments. Thanks!